# Export to CSV w/o Header or Quotes

Tags: powershell

I need to create a new CSV from an existing table, but I need to add a column before and have no headers, or quotes around the data within the cells.  I noticed if I open the file, save it, quotes are removed but this file will be going external at 1AM  nightly
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KW4hs.png) [Example in Windows Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0jiu.png)

```
$NewCSV = '\\server2\export.csv'
$Assets = (import-csv '\\server1\PCList.csv' | Where-Object {$_.PCNumber -ne ''}).PCnumber | ForEach-Object {

[pscustomobject]@{
'h1' = 'IT Support'
'h2' = $_+'.acme.net'
}

} | Export-Csv $NewCSV
```

I have seen usage of Outfile but that breaks my columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're running *PowerShell (Core) 7+*:

```sh
... | 
  ConvertTo-Csv -UseQuotes Never | 
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
      Set-Content $NewCSV
```

If you're running *Windows PowerShell*:

```sh
... | 
  ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | 
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
      ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '"' } |
        Set-Content $NewCSV
```

Note:

- [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv) is the *in-memory* equivalent of [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv), which therefore allows skipping the first output object, representing the CSV *header*, via [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object).
  [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) can then be used to save the results to a file. Use its `-Encoding` parameter to control the character encoding.

  - In Windows PowerShell only, `-NoTypeInformation` is additionally needed to suppress the usually undesired type-annotation line that is  emitted before the header line; the same goes for `Export-Csv`.
- The following applies to both `ConvertTo-Csv` and `Export-Csv`:

  - In *Windows PowerShell*, all CSV column values are *invariably* double-quoted (enclosed in `"..."`), but in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* you can control the double-quoting behavior via the `-UseQuotes` parameter. Additionally, you can choose to *selectively* double-quote columns (fields), via the `-QuoteFields` parameter.

Comment: My apologies, this does work.

I also figured add adding in the correct single header

[array]$newRow = "IT Support"
$csv = Get-Content $NewCSV
$newCSV = $newRow + $csv | Set-Content $NewCSV

This saves me so much time, thank you!

Comment: If I may, I noticed the file when opened in notepad has a trailing entry, I attempted to wrap it in trimend() to no luck.  any help?

Comment: @JustSomeDude, if you really want to create a file without a trailing newline try `($newRow + $csv) -join [Environment]::NewLine | Set-Content -NoNewLine $NewCav`

Comment: I wish I could say it wouldn't be a problem, but the vendor I'm working with didn't even know we could use their API to post updates, soooo.  With that said, this is amazing it appears to be perfect.  I guess we'll find out on Tuesday when the import happens.